# Does Django RestFramework supports async views and class?

Tags: python-3.x, django, asynchronous, django-rest-framework, async-await

It will be helpful if someone helps me with a clear cut answer. If Yes any suggestion how to approach... coz, I try to use async with DRF but I am always ending with
"AssertionError: Expected a Response, HttpResponse or HttpStreamingResponse to be returned from the view, but received a <class 'coroutine'>" this error

Comment: It's now supported as a [third party library](https://github.com/em1208/adrf) though it lacks proper documentation and the overall state is unclear

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no.

*(as for 02.12.2021, djangorestframework==3.12.4)*

`asnyc` is not mentioned once in [DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

> Documentation search `async` No results found

Django does "support" async so DRF should too but all DRF features were programmed with non-async in mind and are not ready to work with async. By making your DRF code async you won't be able to use all DRF features flawlessly.

Comment: Thank you bro.. I found a package named django ninja to use async with rest frame work, its great. But, stuck with an issue. Iam working in a project were I have to get the data from React frontend. If it is Django rest, I can use(request.data) but in django-ninja no idea to process. Any suggestion?

Comment: I am not familiar with this lib but from its [docs](https://django-ninja.rest-framework.com/tutorial/body/) it seem that you need to define what you expect and add it as parameter to you view. This lib will validate received data using Pydantic models `Under the hood Django Ninja uses Pydantic models with all their power and benefits`

Comment: Ohh, Thanks you bro.. let me check it..

Answer (score -1):

Just use fastapi, you will thank me later